# Check validity of simple random variable tails inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be random variables, and $N$ a positive real number.

Check whether $\mathbb{P}(\{ |A| \geq N \}) \geq \mathbb{P}(\{ |A + B| \geq N \}) $

### My attempt

From the triangle inequality $|A + B| \leq |A| + |B|$ but I can neither prove nor disprove the above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  false. Take $A=0$ and $B=N=1$.

Comment: thanks ! I was starting to think it was false but didn't think to check it with constant RVs.

Answer (score 2):

This is false.

Take $A = -1$ and $B >N$. The LHS is $0$ then while the RHS is $1$.

Also the converse inequality fails.